# trying to minimalize the js code and want to increase the performance speed in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to avoid to write the number of lines since the response is same for all the fields so I tried to use for loop with categorizing the fields['mandatory', 'optional'] but still I need to write twice time for loop. Is this possible to write more efficiently without compromising the performance in one go.

```
    //mandatory
obj.required['test1' + number] = true;
obj.visible['test1' + number] = true;
obj.required['test2' + number] = true;
obj.visible['test2' + number] = true;
obj.required['test3' + number] = true;
obj.visible['test3' + number] = true;
//optional
obj.visible['test4' + number] = true;
obj.visible['test5' + number] = true;
```

**Tried with for loop:**

```
var mandatoryField = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
var optionalField = ['test4', 'test5'];

for(var i=0; i<mandatoryField.length; i++) {
obj.required[madatoryField[i] + number] = true;
obj.visible[madatoryField[i] + number] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the structure of the fields?

```js
const obj = {
  visible: {
    test1: false,
    test2: false,
    test3: false,
    test4: false,
    test5: false,
    test6: false,
    test7: false,
    test8: false,
  },
  required: {
    test1: false,
    test2: false,
    test3: false,
    test4: false,
    test5: false,
    test6: false,
    test7: false,
    test8: false,
  },
};
const fields = [
  { field: 'test1', required: true },
  { field: 'test2', required: true },
  { field: 'test3', required: true },
  { field: 'test4' },
  { field: 'test5' },
];

fields.forEach(({ field, required }) => {
  const key = field; // `${field}${number}`;

  obj.visible[key] = true;

  if (required) {
    obj.required[key] = true;
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this wll help you to achieve this in one iteration.

```js
var mandatoryField = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
var optionalField = ['test4', 'test5'];

const limit = new Array(Math.max(mandatoryField.length, optionalField.length)).fill(0);
limit.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(mandatoryField[index]) {
        obj.required[mandatoryField[index] + number] = true;
        obj.visible[mandatoryField[index] + number] = true;
    }
    if(optionalField[index]) {
        obj.visible[optionalField[index] + number] = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Er, "ReferenceError: madatoryField is not defined".

Comment: Not just `madatoryField`(that must be a typo), `obj` and `i` also will throw `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @Andy typo error. Fixed that. This is only a pseudo code.

Comment: @NalinRanjan This is only a pseudo code that suggest an implemntation to this issue. The user can create his solution from this logic. I clearly know this will throw a reference error for `obj` and `number`